# Melhor biblioteca HTML para Android Studio

Tags: html, android-studio

Alguém pode me dar sugestões de bibliotecas HTML para se usar no Android Studio, ou qual seria melhor forma de se colocar HTML sem ser com o que já vem nativo?

Exemplo: [Html-TextView](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview)

Comment: Tem esse modelo: http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está citada por você é a mais famosa, achei outra semelhante que é a [HtmlSpanner](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner)